# Beagle Board Black Wireless Connecting to the internet

Tags: beagleboneblack, beagleboard

I've spent most of today trying to properly connect my boar to WiFi but it does not see mt work. this is what I used

**sudo connmanctl**

connmanctl> **enable wifi**

Enabled wifi

connmanctl> **scan wifi**

Scan completed for wifi

connmanctl> **services**

*AO TNCAPA97AB9

wifi_506583d4fc5e_544e434150413937414239_managed_psk

wifi_506583d4fc5e_4254576966692d776974682d464f4e_managed_none

connmanctl> **agent on**

Agent registered

connmanctl> **connect wifi_506583d4fc5e_544e434150413937414239_managed_psk**

Passphrase? **xxxxxxxxxxx**

connected wifi_506583d4fc5e_544e434150413937414239_managed_psk

connmanctl> **quit**

Once all this is done I still don't seem to have access to internet. Could this be due to my computer settings?

Comment: Do you have a Wifi Dongle connected to your Beaglebone? And if yes, what's the name and model number? It might not be compatible with the BBB.

Answer (score 0):

You can use connmanctl technologies to check if your Wifi adapter is powered up and connected. You also have to configure your connection settings and assign a static  IP to your BBB. For more information, you can check [Setting up Wifi on BeagleBone](https://deeplyembedded.org/set-up-wifi-beaglebone-black/). And between, this question is more suitable for Electrical Stack Exchange rather than Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

I also followed the same steps and was not working.
Then I followed the steps mentioned in the below link.

https://dougreese.com/beaglebone-black-wireless-initial-setup-and-wifi-connect.html

It is working fine for me now.

The only difference I see is the below command.

*connmanctl> tether wifi disable*

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).